# Subtraction of perpendicular vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Okay, so I'm reading a proof which shows that the dot product of two perpendicular vectors is 0.
I am kinda confused by the beginning of the [proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaECc.png), the part where it says that for two perpendicular vectors **v** and **w**, the hypotenuse is **v-w**. Why is this so? Am I drawing the [sketches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idnLF.png) for addition and subtraction incorrectly?
The [Figure 1.7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cq0Qc.png) shows that the hypotenuse is the addition of the two vectors, but the proof says that it's the subtraction.

Of course, if the hypotenuse is represented as **v+b** the proof wouldn't stand

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Your sketch is quite correct, but probably you misinterpret what you see. Your $v-w$ is indeed a hypotenuse – of the right triangle with right angle at the end of vector $-w$. It is also the hypotenuse of the triangle with right angle at the origin in the first quadrant.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Math.SE. As you can see from your draft, the length of the vectors $\boldsymbol{v+w}$ and  $\boldsymbol{v-w}$ is the same when $\boldsymbol{v\perp w}$. the only thing that changes is the angle of the vector, so you can conveniently assume that the hypothenuse is $\boldsymbol{v-w}$ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sketch shows perfectly that the hypotenuse is what the author claims it is. The problem is that you are on a vector space, so every vector is pinned to the origin (otherwise you would be working on an *affine space*). This may be the confusion point. When the author says that the third side *is* $v-w$, he or she means that this side corresponds to the vector $v-w$ (which is necessarily pinned at the origin) translated to some position in the affine plane.

The hypotenuse of the right triangle defined by $v$ and $w$ has in any case the same *direction* as $v-w$ (and not the same direction as $v+w$). Note that $w-v$ would also work, which is something you should expect (since the roles of $v$ and $w$ are symmetric).